# Move menu bar has moved after site migration

Tags: theme

since site mirgration of my site all of a sudden my menu has moved

http://kferreiradesigns.com.au/

anyone know what file i need to edit to move it back

thanks in-advance[image]

Comment: link says, this account has been suspended

Comment: unsuspended now i had mailware sorry its up again

Comment: Any suggestions? :( bit stuck on what to do and can't find any sites to help

Comment: Hi add margin:auto in #nav id ex:- #nav{margin:auto;}

Answer (score 0):

That is simple navigate To your css file  /d80ccaa0ff316f9f00cab516a70d3b96.css
and edit it like below on line no:27

```
 * {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;  
   }
```

basicaly it keeps the content in center.